# how to make a query calculate in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table

```
id daily    pre_daily  created_at
1  2000     34.50      2019-01-01 14:08:45
2  2450     30.4       2019-01-02 14:08:45
3  3500     33.7       2019-01-03 14:08:45
```

I want to generate the following output

```
id  daily  accumulation
1   2000   2000
2   2450   4450
3   3500   7950
```

How can I make calculations like this ? please help
I want my data to recap for one month with calculations like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `correlated subquery`

```
select t.id, t.daily,
       (select sum(daily) from tab where id <= t.id ) as accumulation
  from tab t
 order by t.id;

id  daily  accumulation
1   2000   2000
2   2450   4450
3   3500   7950
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2d4bbe896fed233be24c386e4b03a427)</kbd>

P.S. If your version is 8-, then you cannot use windows analytic functions.

Comment: @Ada you're welcome bro :)